# Where can I put my global code in Kohana 3.3?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

Say I want a constant, a function or a class to be available in all my models, views and controllers code (within a particular web site (application)). Where can I put them? I don't mind importing them explicitly in every file I need them in but I don't know how (simple `require_once` does not seem to work).

Comment: What is wrong with `APPPATH/classes/` as a place for a Utility class, e.g.? Did you already look into the [autoloading page on the docu](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/autoloading)?

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in the vendor folder (in application/vendor or modules/MOD/vendor). Then you can load it like this:

```
require Kohana::find_file('vendor', 'folder/file','ext');
```

You can read up more on this in the [user guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/files#vendor-extensions)

Now, it should be stated you should in general not use functions or globals.

Comment: Note that if you place it in a module, you can use the init.php file to always load it. Otherwise, place it in the bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I declare Constants in Bootstrap.php and create my own [Helpers](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/helpers) for general functions under `application/classes/Helpers`.

If you need to integrate a third party library into Kohana or want to make code available to other Kohana users consider creating a [module](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/modules) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can define all your constants in new php file and place it in the `application/classes` directory. In your Template controller or in the main controller like Welcome or Website, just place the code in the `__constructor()`

```
require_once Kohana::find_file( 'classes', 'filename' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put your constant variables in the `bootstrap.php` file because this is loaded by the framework before every request.

You can simply put your classes in the root of the `classes` directory, the framework will find.

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me...

In application/config/constants.php:

```
define('SOME_COOL_CONSTANT', 'foo');
return array();
```

In index.php:

```
Kohana::$config->load('constants');
```

SOME_COOL_CONSTANT should then be available globally.